# How can I turn the first row into a column and have it still line up with its multiple values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The first row represents years but I want to turn it to a column. However, I'm not sure how to do this since it has multiple values.

I tried the stack function and tried setting the first column has the index.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Gets working directory
cwd = os.getcwd()

# Changes directory
os.chdir("C:/Users/Andy/Desktop")

# Location of the file
file = "C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/AquacultureTradeFull.xls"

# Reading the excel file
aqua = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = "FishShellfish_M_Yearly-Full")

# Renaming our column
aqua_new = aqua.columns.values[0] = "measurement"

# Removing irrelevant rows
aqua_new = aqua.drop([31, 32, 33])

aqua_new = aqua.stack()
aqua_new
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZktM.jpg "original df"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhnYZ.jpg "post stack"

Answer (score 0):

You may approach the problem like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# loading data from excel file
df = pd.read_excel(
    'AquacultureTradeFull.xls',
    sheet_name='FishShellfish_M_Yearly-Full',
    skiprows=1,  # skip first row
    nrows=30)  # read only 30 rows, alternative is 'skipfooter' argument

# fill empty cells in the very first column (pounds or dollars)
df.iloc[:, 0].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

# add appropriate names for the first 2 columns
df.columns = ['VolumeOrValue', 'Product'] + list(df.columns[2:])

# create multiindex from the first two columns
df = df.set_index(['VolumeOrValue', 'Product'], drop=True)

# transpose dataframe
df = df.T
```

Now `df` has index:

```
Index(['1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997',
       '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006',
       '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015',
       '2016', '2017', 'Jan-Oct 17', 'Jan-Oct 18'],
      dtype='object')
```

...and columns:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Value\n(1,000 U.S. dollars)', 'Volume\n(1,000 pounds)'], ['Atlantic salmon, fillets', 'Atlantic salmon, fresh', 'Atlantic salmon, frozen', 'Clams 5/', 'Mussels 5/', 'Ornamental fish', 'Oysters 5/', 'Pacific salmon, fresh 1/', 'Pacific salmon, frozen 1/', 'Salmon, canned and prepared 2/', 'Scallops 5/', 'Shrimp, fresh and prepared 4/', 'Shrimp, frozen', 'Tilapia 3/', 'Trout, fresh and frozen', 'Trout, live']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [14, 1, 7, 2, 8, 0, 9, 13, 12, 11, 6, 4, 3, 10, 8, 0, 9, 13, 12, 11, 5, 14, 1, 7, 6, 4, 3, 10, 15, 2]],
           names=['VolumeOrValue', 'Product'])
```

So one can use `df` like this:

```
>>> df_pounds = df.loc[:, 'Volume\n(1,000 pounds)']
>>> df_pounds.loc['1995', 'Atlantic salmon, fillets']
19534.20755454
```